# "interest + gerund" or "interest in + gerund"

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

Which is more appropriate usage:

1. "Please let me know your interest attending the game"
   or
2. "Please let me know your interest in attending the game".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Macmillan Dictionary notes](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/interest_1), "interest" in this sense is used with the preposition "in."

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interest+attending%2Cinterest+in+attending&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) confirms that "interest in attending" is far, far more common than "interest attending."

So "interest in attending" is correct.